# variable created on heap was not deleted in C++

Tags: c++, queue, new-operator, delete-operator

I was looking into BFS search code provide in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/):

```
// Program to print BFS traversal from a given 
// source vertex. BFS(int s) traverses vertices  
// reachable from s. 
#include<iostream> 
#include <list> 

using namespace std; 

// This class represents a directed graph using 
// adjacency list representation 
class Graph 
{ 
    int V;    // No. of vertices 

    // Pointer to an array containing adjacency 
    // lists 
    list<int> *adj;    
public: 
    Graph(int V);  // Constructor 

    // function to add an edge to graph 
    void addEdge(int v, int w);  

    // prints BFS traversal from a given source s 
    void BFS(int s);   
}; 

Graph::Graph(int V) 
{ 
    this->V = V; 
    adj = new list<int>[V]; 
} 

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) 
{ 
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list. 
} 

void Graph::BFS(int s) 
{ 
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited 
    bool *visited = new bool[V]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
        visited[i] = false; 

    // Create a queue for BFS 
    list<int> queue; 

    // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it 
    visited[s] = true; 
    queue.push_back(s); 

    // 'i' will be used to get all adjacent 
    // vertices of a vertex 
    list<int>::iterator i; 

    while(!queue.empty()) 
    { 
        // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it 
        s = queue.front(); 
        cout << s << " "; 
        queue.pop_front(); 

        // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued 
        // vertex s. If a adjacent has not been visited,  
        // then mark it visited and enqueue it 
        for (i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); ++i) 
        { 
            if (!visited[*i]) 
            { 
                visited[*i] = true; 
                queue.push_back(*i); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 

// Driver program to test methods of graph class 
int main() 
{ 
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram 
    Graph g(4); 
    g.addEdge(0, 1); 
    g.addEdge(0, 2); 
    g.addEdge(1, 2); 
    g.addEdge(2, 0); 
    g.addEdge(2, 3); 
    g.addEdge(3, 3); 

    cout << "Following is Breadth First Traversal "
         << "(starting from vertex 2) \n"; 
    g.BFS(2); 

    return 0; 
}
```

In the constructor of Graph class they created a adjacency list in the heap but they never use a delete to free the memory. My question is as following

a) Is there any chance of memory leak?

If there is any memory leak how could we solve the problem?

Comment: The code was definitely written by a Java programmer so yes, the code is full of leaks.

Comment: Here the code in the ctor is all you need to reproduce the problem. That itself would give a [mcve]. Any memory allocated in the heap should be freed when the resource is no longer used. You need a `delete` corresponding to every `new`.

Comment: From what I've seen from that site, the ideas behind the solutions maybe ok and are useful, but the code that is written to implement the solutions is usually full of memory leaks and/or do not use legal C++ .  If you see `new[]`, replace it with `vector` -- if you see a variable length array being declared, replace that also with `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are leaks.

1. Leak 1 is `new list<int>[V];`
2. Leak 2 is `new bool[V];`

Looks like some guy with Java or C# background wrote this piece of code. To fix the leaks use `delete[]` in the function `void Graph::BFS(int s)` also use a destructor to delete the list.

Then, you might consider `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any chance of memory leak?

Yes, there is a high chance for a memory leak.

> If there is any memory leak how could we solve the problem?

Generally, this can be solved by implementing a destructor. Then again, according to the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), we would need a *copy-constructor* as well, just in case an end user decides to copy one list to another.

But we could actually sidestep this by *not dynamically-allocating in the first place!* Let's reimplement with `std::vector`:

```
class Graph 
{ 
    int V;

    vector<list<int>> adj;    
public: 
    Graph(int V);

    // ...
}; 

Graph::Graph(int V)
{ 
    this->V = V;
    adj.assign(V, list<int>());     // std::vector::assign
} 

void Graph::BFS(int s) 
{ 
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited 
    vector<bool> visited(V);                       //  see note below  *
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
        visited[i] = false; 

    // Create a queue for BFS 
    list<int> queue;

    // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it 
    visited[s] = true; 
    queue.push_back(s); 

    // 'i' will be used to get all adjacent 
    // vertices of a vertex 
    list<int>::iterator i; 

    while(!queue.empty()) 
    { 
        // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it 
        s = queue.front(); 
        cout << s << " "; 
        queue.pop_front(); 

        // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued 
        // vertex s. If a adjacent has not been visited,  
        // then mark it visited and enqueue it 
        for (i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); ++i) 
        { 
            if (!visited[*i]) 
            { 
                visited[*i] = true; 
                queue.push_back(*i); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

There are a ton of other minor issues with this code, but I shall leave that as an exercise for the reader.

<sup>**Note: [`vector<bool>` isn't your normal vector.](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool)*</sup>